# Tabhost returns null in android when comes back from activitiy and goto tab frament

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

When I open the application for the first time my tab is working fine. When I come back and go to the fragment page some times it returns null. Please help me ! What am I doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
public class TabsFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<ShareWinLeaderBoardTabModel> mShareWinLeaderBoardTabModelList;
    public TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, ArrayList<ShareWinLeaderBoardTabModel> shareWinLeaderBoardTabModelList) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        mShareWinLeaderBoardTabModelList = shareWinLeaderBoardTabModelList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        /*ShareWinLeaderBoardTabModel model = Once that is donemShareWinLeaderBoardTabModelList.get(position);
        return new ShareWinLeaderBoardListFragment(model);*/

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ShareWinLeaderBoardTabModel model = mShareWinLeaderBoardTabModelList.get(position);
            return new ShareWinLeaderBoardListFragment(model);
        case 1:
            ShareWinLeaderBoardTabModel model1 = mShareWinLeaderBoardTabModelList.get(position);
            return new ShareWinLeaderBoardListFragment(model1);
        case 2:
            ShareWinLeaderBoardTabModel model2 = mShareWinLeaderBoardTabModelList.get(position);
            return new ShareWinLeaderBoardListFragment(model2);
        case 3:
            ShareWinLeaderBoardTabModel model3 = mShareWinLeaderBoardTabModelList.get(position);
            return new ShareWinLeaderBoardListFragment(model3);
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mShareWinLeaderBoardTabModelList.size();
    }

}
```

When I press back there is some problem with the tab host. Tabs are coming fine but they are showing blank fragments. Any Help?

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`